# Problems with with my own custom CSS in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dictionary, variables, overwrite

I’m trying to work with a custom **CSS** that allows me to override the **bootstrap** default variables.

For this I find the bootstrap documentation the following example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#importing

I have now set this up accordingly - in variant A: If I now change variables such as `$primary` or `$secondary`, this works wonderfully.

But if I want to extend an existing map, then I have the following problem:

I want to add another color `$tertiary` to the map `$theme-colors`, I apply the following example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#add-to-map

I add the code to my **custom.css** but then I get the following error:

> Error: Undefined variable:"$theme-colors".

How do I have to do that I can make all customizations against the bootstrap default in this **custom.css**?

Thank you all, Reto

Comment: Can you show us your scss code pls ?

Comment: in the meantime I have found the solution myself, it seems that BS4 is slightly different from bS5 here. If someone has the same problem, here is the solution:
https://blog.assistancy.be/blog/bootstrap-5-override-theme-colors-sass?fbclid=IwAR1Wi4YfsnG2gVbRiGfZ1RGsMVDojmKEidKiJM2FGsvJvLPGcdjnSdA3v0k